# CollectionView in ContainerView

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicontainerview

I have a simple `ViewController` and a `containerView` in it.
I coded the containerView to a simple `collectionView` with a UICollectionViewCell which has a UIView in it with a background color.

I set the delegate and datasource in the contaierViewController.swift file and implemented the required functions.

But when starting the simulator the parentViewController doesn't show the UICollectionView from the ContainerView...

If I shrink the `collectionView` in the containerView and add a Label next to the `collectionView`, then the parentViewController let me see the label but not the collectionView.

Why is that happening?

Can anyone help me? Btw. I have another question. Does working a lot with ContainerViews cause memory leaks? If yes, how can I avoid them and still use a lot of containerViews?

It would be awesome if someone could give that problem attention.

Comment: are you using constraints?

Comment: Please, provide some code

Comment: Create new viewController for collectionView, make the connection between containerView to new viewController(embed segue), pass data to new viewController via prepare for segue method

Comment: thanks for trying to help, I just failed with accessing the custom Cell